# How can I add a Buy / Sell Signal when all 3 Supertrend lines are green / red and only show the signal one time?

Tags: pine-script

Here is the code:

```
//@version=4
study("Supertrend", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
showsignals_3 = input(title="Show Triple Buy/Sell Signal", type=input.bool, defval=true)
Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=12, group="Supertrend 1")
src = input(hl2, title="Source", group="Supertrend 1")
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0, group="Supertrend 1")
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 1")
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=false, group="Supertrend 1")
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 1")
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
///alertcondition(buySignal, title="SuperTrend Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!")
///alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SuperTrend Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!")
changeCond = trend != trend[1]
///alertcondition(changeCond, title="SuperTrend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")


/////


Periods_1 = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10, group="Supertrend 2")
src_1 = input(hl2, title="Source", group="Supertrend 2")
Multiplier_1 = input(title="ATR Multiplier_1", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=1.0, group="Supertrend 2")
changeATR_1= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 2")
showsignals_1 = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=false, group="Supertrend 2")
highlighting_1 = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 2")
atr2_1 = sma(tr, Periods_1)
atr_1= changeATR_1 ? atr(Periods_1) : atr2_1
up_1=src_1-(Multiplier_1*atr_1)
up_11 = nz(up_1[1],up_1)
up_1 := close[1] > up_11 ? max(up_1,up_11) : up_1
dn_1=src_1+(Multiplier_1*atr_1)
dn_11 = nz(dn_1[1], dn_1)
dn_1 := close[1] < dn_11 ? min(dn_1, dn_11) : dn_1
trend_1 = 1
trend_1 := nz(trend_1[1], trend_1)
trend_1 := trend_1 == -1 and close > dn_11 ? 1 : trend_1 == 1 and close < up_11 ? -1 : trend_1
up_1Plot = plot(trend_1 == 1 ? up_1 : na, title="Up_1 Trend_1", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal_1 = trend_1 == 1 and trend_1[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal_1 ? up_1 : na, title="Up_1Trend_1 Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal_1 and showsignals_1 ? up_1 : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dn_1Plot = plot(trend_1 == 1 ? na : dn_1, title="Down Trend_1", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal_1 = trend_1 == -1 and trend_1[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal_1 ? dn_1 : na, title="DownTrend_1 Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal_1 and showsignals_1 ? dn_1 : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot_1 = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
fill(mPlot_1, up_1Plot, title="Up_1Trend_1 Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot_1, dn_1Plot, title="DownTrend_1 Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
///alertcondition(buySignal_1, title="Supertrend Buy", message="Supertrend Buy!")
///alertcondition(sellSignal_1, title="Supertrend Sell", message="Supertrend Sell!")
changeCond_1 = trend_1 != trend_1[1]
///alertcondition(changeCond_1, title="Supertrend Direction Change", message="Supertrend has changed direction!")


/////

Periods_2 = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=11, group="Supertrend 3")
src_2 = input(hl2, title="Source", group="Supertrend 3")
Multiplier_2 = input(title="ATR Multiplier_2", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=2.0, group="Supertrend 3")
changeATR_2= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 3")
showsignals_2 = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=false, group="Supertrend 3")
highlighting_2 = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true, group="Supertrend 3")
atr2_2 = sma(tr, Periods_2)
atr_2= changeATR_2 ? atr(Periods_2) : atr2_2
up_2=src_2-(Multiplier_2*atr_2)
up_212 = nz(up_2[1],up_2)
up_2 := close[1] > up_212 ? max(up_2,up_212) : up_2
dn_2=src_2+(Multiplier_2*atr_2)
dn_212 = nz(dn_2[1], dn_2)
dn_2 := close[1] < dn_212 ? min(dn_2, dn_212) : dn_2
trend_2 = 1
trend_2 := nz(trend_2[1], trend_2)
trend_2 := trend_2 == -1 and close > dn_212 ? 1 : trend_2 == 1 and close < up_212 ? -1 : trend_2
up_2Plot = plot(trend_2 == 1 ? up_2 : na, title="Up_2 Trend_2", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal_2 = trend_2 == 1 and trend_2[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal_2 ? up_2 : na, title="Up_2Trend_2 Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal_2 and showsignals_2 ? up_2 : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dn_2Plot = plot(trend_2 == 1 ? na : dn_2, title="Down Trend_2", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal_2 = trend_2 == -1 and trend_2[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal_2 ? dn_2 : na, title="DownTrend_2 Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal_2 and showsignals_2 ? dn_2 : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot_2 = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
fill(mPlot_2, up_2Plot, title="Up_2Trend_2 Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot_2, dn_2Plot, title="DownTrend_2 Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
///alertcondition(buySignal_2, title="Supertrend Buy", message="Supertrend Buy!")
///alertcondition(sellSignal_2, title="Supertrend Sell", message="Supertrend Sell!")
changeCond_2 = trend_2 != trend_2[1]
///alertcondition(changeCond_2, title="Supertrend Direction Change", message="Supertrend has changed direction!")

////
///plotshape(buySignal and showsignals_3 ? up : na and buySignal_1 and showsignals_3 ? up_1 : na and buySignal_2 and showsignals_3 ? up_2 : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
///plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals_3 ? dn : na and sellSignal_1 and showsignals_3 ? dn_1 : na and sellSignal_2 and showsignals_3 ? dn_2 : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

isLongOpen = false
isLongOpen := nz(isLongOpen[1]) 

longOpenSignal = trend == 1 and trend_1 == 1 and trend_2 == 1 and not isLongOpen


if (longOpenSignal)
    isLongOpen := true

plotshape(series=longOpenSignal, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

alertcondition(buySignal and buySignal_1 and buySignal_2, title="Supertrend Buy", message="Supertrend Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal and sellSignal_1 and sellSignal_2, title="Supertrend Sell", message="Supertrend Sell!")
////


//////


len = input(200, minval=1, title="Length", group="EMA")
src_ema = input(close, title="Source", group="EMA")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500, group="EMA")
out = ema(src_ema, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)


/////
```

I want to plot a Buy/Sell signal when uptrend/downtrends starts in all 3 supertrend line

I tried the following but it doesn't work properly:

```
isLongOpen = false
isLongOpen := nz(isLongOpen[1]) 

longOpenSignal = trend == 1 and trend_1 == 1 and trend_2 == 1 and not isLongOpen


if (longOpenSignal)
    isLongOpen := true

plotshape(series=longOpenSignal, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
```

I also want to show the signal only once and not on every candle.

The existing code adds the signal to all the candles and does not respect the conditions set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the lines align, it will plot an arrow only in the beginning.

```
cond_long = trend == 1 and trend_1 == 1 and trend_2 == 1
cond_short = trend == -1 and trend_1 == -1 and trend_2 == -1

plotshape(cond_long and not cond_long[1], location = location.bottom, style=shape.triangleup, color = color.green, size = size.small)
plotshape(cond_short and not cond_short[1], location = location.top, style=shape.triangledown, color = color.red, size = size.small)
```

From here you can play with the plotshapes as you want.

Comment: @Sagar1996 great, don't forget to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted